# No ethernet on RPi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, ethernet, dhcp

I have 3 RPi 3B+, all exhibit the same behaviour. 2 were bought a while ago, one more recently.

When starting, on lucky days, they will get an IP from DHCP. If not lucky or upon first reboot, they no longer get an IP. Using ifconfig eth0 up to set a fixed IP succeeds, but still no network access. I ping to/from them, but network sniffing shows nothing.
I've connected them directly to another machine, to bypass the switch, no difference.

I'm using the latest Raspbian image (2019-07-10), just put it on SD card and boot (and enable SSH).

If I disconnect an RPi3B+, put instead a 2B and put the same SD card in the 2B, works like a charm.

I've tried some 2.4A USB power supply. I'm otherwise using a voltage regulator, hooked its output to oscilloscope and checked, I'm getting Vavg = 5.01V, Vmin = 4.93V, Vmax = 5.05V. No dipping, so I'm pretty sure it's not a power issue (this regulator is rated 3A @ 5V).

Any suggestion?

---

Edit:

I get the yellow LED lit, and it blinks when I try pinging. All my equipment is 1GB compatible.
Sometimes on boot up I get DHCP request packets, most times, nothing. Getting DHCP packet does not necessarily result in getting an IP, but then, setting up a fixed IP allows communication.
When communication doesn't work, using dhclient doesn't cause any packet to be intercepted by network sniffer.

Comment: There is a significant difference between the Ethernet interfaces - the Pi3+ has Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I added details to my question.

Comment: When you say "no difference", does it mean that the RPi sometimes gets a DHCP lease from that "another machine"?

Comment: No, there's no DHCP on that network. I set a static IP and the 2 machines can't communicate. No traffic arrives on the interface of "that other machine" (tcpdump -i eth1... no output). So having or not a DHCP would make no difference, prior to setting the IP, I see no incoming packets.

Comment: try upping the voltage from your regulator - vMax 5.2v vMin shouldn't be less than 5.0v.  Make sure these are the voltages at the Pi end of the power lead when the Pi is booting up.  Outside of that,  use a fresh image on your SD card (I.e. don't put it in a Pi 2 first!) and also check the image checksum matches. Only download the image from the official download page.

Comment: My Second thought relates to your ethernet cables and whether they are good enough to fully support gigabit ethernet.  Cases do occur where the equipment will support Gigabit, so try to but fail due to poor quality cabling.  But won't step down to 100Mbit (because both ends claim to support 1Gig).

Comment: @Charemer The port on a RPi 3B+ is called "Gigabit" but it can only serve 300 MBit. This is because the wired port is using the USB bridge that limits the speed. Real gigabit is only given on a RPi 4B.

Comment: @Charemer: ok will try bumping up the voltage. The SD card was put in the Pi2 just as a last resort comparison. The cable itself is usually connecting a NUC with a Gb connection, no problem. I've also tried several cables. However, one thing I haven't tried yet is forcing the port to 100 Mb on the switch.

Comment: It's been tested and works on another router down to 4.5V. Now running at 5.1V it works "better", but I don't get network in 100% of cases, unless I limit the switch port to 100 Mb. I suspect this is actually an issue more on the switch side, though other devices are working happily. Have suspicions RPi might be more sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is somewhere between the switch and the RPi.
Switch was a DLink DGS-1210-24.
I changed switch, no more issue.

As a workaround when still using that (manageable) switch, I had forced the port to 100 Mb FD, obviously not taking advantage of Gb Ethernet, but I don't need it, while I really need Ethernet...